# Logging using multiprocessing

Tags: python, logging, multiprocessing

I do have the following `logger` class (as logger.py):

```
import logging, logging.handlers
import config

log = logging.getLogger('myLog')

def start():
    "Function sets up the logging environment."
    log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt='%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(message)s', datefmt='%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S')

    if config.logfile_enable:
        filehandler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(config.logfile_name, maxBytes=config.logfile_maxsize,backupCount=config.logfile_backupCount)
        filehandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        filehandler.setFormatter(formatter)
        log.addHandler(filehandler)

    console = logging.StreamHandler()
    console.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    console.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('[%(levelname)s] %(message)s')) # nicer format for console
    log.addHandler(console)

    # Levels are: debug, info, warning, error, critical.
    log.debug("Started logging to %s [maxBytes: %d, backupCount: %d]" % (config.logfile_name, config.logfile_maxsize, config.logfile_backupCount))

def stop():
    "Function closes and cleans up the logging environment."
    logging.shutdown()
```

For logging, I launch `logger.start()` once, and then import `from logger import log` at any project file. Then I just use `log.debug()` and `log.error()` when needed.
It works fine from everywhere on the script (different classes, functions and files) but it won't work on different processes lanuched through the multiprocessing class.

I get the following error: `No handlers could be found for logger "myLog"`.

What can I do?

Comment: Where do you initialize the "second" process and is the second process execute the upside snippet of code?

Comment: Well, I didn't initialize it again in the second process. Makes sense why the handlers couldn't be found. But I can't intilize a different logger object to the same file and expect both object will log correctly. Or am I wrong?

Comment: maybe this is relevant? http://docs.python.org/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer Thank you. please post it as answer so i can choose it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

from the python docs: `logging to a single file from multiple processes is not supported, because there is no standard way to serialize access to a single file across multiple processes in Python.`

See: http://docs.python.org/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes

BTW: What I do in this situation, is use Scribe which is a distributed logging aggregator, that I log to via TCP. This allows me to log all **servers** I have to the same place, not just all processes.

See this project: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ScribeHandler