# Separate logs for each process using multiprocessing?

Tags: python, logging, multiprocessing

I am using multiprocessing with python 2.7. I would like each subprocess to log to its own file (filename = procname.pid.log) and NOT to the standarg log output. So far, I have been able to create each log file by creating a logger and FileHandler() in each subprocesses start() method, but I can't stop the log messages from also showing up in the parent log output. I understand that the parent environment is inherited, but how do I shut it off in the child processes?

My child processes are implemented as classes derived from multiprocessing.Process. I have avoided using logging.basicConfig, as I have heard it can only be executed once. I have seen this code suggested:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.propogate = False
```

But it has no effect.

I am not at all clear how the logging propogates up. I *think* that when I call getLogger, I have a new logger created called `root.__module__`, but I don't know how to get the root to stop printint to the screen.

Comment: I am confused. I thought you can't log to the same file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665090/logging-using-multiprocessing

Answer (score 0):

Is this on POSIX? Configure your logging *after* process creation. Then nothing should be inherited by the child processes from the parent process.

BTW note the correct spelling: `propagate`.

Also, see [this post](http://plumberjack.blogspot.co.uk/search?q=multiprocessing) for more information.